# What is this package source starting with gav:// and how to upgrade a package from this source?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kotlin, apache-commons-compress

Came across the following artefact in one of the docker images that I built. So, wondering what this package source (`gav://`) is and how can I upgrade it?

`gav://org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.19`

Comment: "gateway anti virus" ... ?

Comment: or in "maven circlex" it could also mean group-artifact-version!!!??

Answer (score 0):

I recently have a similar issue, upon some research it seems to be a Java package managed by Maven. To upgrade them you might use the command:

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:version
```